# Nested foreach with changing index size

Tags: r, foreach, dplyr, doparallel

I'm trying to obtain the return of daily prices for each stock I have. The data is cross-sectionnal and very large. Thus I use doParallel and nested foreach.

Here is the code I've been using so far. (this is a reproduceable example)

and here is a reproduce-able example

```
stock_name <- as.data.frame(sample(x = 1:100, size = 250, replace=TRUE))
price <- as.data.frame(sample(x = 1:100, size = 1000,replace=TRUE))

## Calculating daily returns. 
stock_list<-as.tbl(distinct(stock_name))
numStock<- as.integer(count(stock_list)) #150 #as.integer(count(stock_list))
nCPUcores = detectCores()
if (nCPUcores < 3) {
  registerDoSEQ()
}else{
  cl = makeCluster(nCPUcores - 1)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
}
d_ret<-c()

foreach (stock=1:numStock, .packages = c("doParallel","foreach","data.table","plyr","dplyr")) %dopar%{
  s<-as.integer(unlist(stock_list[stock,]))

  stock_price <- as.matrix(price[which(stock_name[1,]==s),])
  u<-nrow(stock_price)

  d_ret<-foreach (p=2:u) %:%{
    c(d_ret,(stock_price[p,]-stock_price[p-1,])/stock_price[p-1,])
  }
}
stopCluster(cl)
 ##--
```

But the code doesn't work. After Florian Prive's remark, I checked the library and it seems that I should write nested foreach loops like this:

```
x <- foreach(b=bvec, .combine='cbind') %:% 
foreach(a=avec, .combine='c') %dopar% {
  sim(a, b)
 }
```

So what I understand is I shouldn't be writing anything between %:% and the second foreach. 
However, in my case, the second loop would change with the first foreach because there aren't the same number of prices for each stocks. Therefore I can't just write ' foreach(a=avec) '.

The second foreach would ideally depend on variable u

```
u<-nrow(stock_price)
```

Is this even possible with the foreach library? 
Thank you for the help

Comment: This is not the way to do nested foreach loops. Please read the documentation.

Comment: @F.Privé I went to have a look,

```
> x <-
+ foreach(b=bvec, .combine='cbind') %:%
+ foreach(a=avec, .combine='c') %dopar% {
+ sim(a, b)
+ }
```
I changed the position of %:% and %dopar%, now I get "stock" not found. Sorry I'm still pretty clueless...

Comment: @F.Privé ok I think I get that I'm not supposed to add code between %:% and the other foreach. But the size of the second foreach depends on the first loop, how do I go to do that ?

Comment: Please edit your question. And make it clearer.

Comment: @F.Privé Changed the question and edited it.

Comment: Is it very important to parallelize both loops? Can't you parallelize only one of them (usually the outer one)? Or divide by 2 the number of cores used by the outer and use 2 in the inner. Also, I'm sure your code can be optimized and improved before thinking about parallelization.

Comment: @F.Privé I tried paralleling the outer one only and after 21hr of processing it still was calculating the stock return... I didn't know I could divide the number of cores to do that, I didn't even think that was possible. Also while I have some experience in R, I'm not that proficient and optimization is not my strong point...

Comment: Try to vectorize the loop of `c(d_ret,(stock_price[p,]-stock_price[p-1,])/stock_price[p-1,])`. And especially avoid growing objects multiple times (`d_ret`). More info there: https://privefl.github.io/blog/why-loops-are-slow-in-r/.

Comment: Ok, thank you Florian, I've been looking at your work, it's pretty cool but hard to get a good grasp of it. I'll give your pages a few read. Thanks !